# Derivation of Mehler kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to get an intuitive feel for Fourier multipliers and using it to derive formulas for kernels. What I do know for instance is that the Laplacian $\Delta$ is multiplication by $M = -\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2$ in Fourier space, in the sense $\Delta = F^{-1} \circ M \circ F$ where $M$ is the multiplication operator, and that this idea can be used to find the heat kernel: the action of $e^{t\Delta}$ is then multiplication by $M' = e^{-t\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2}$ in Fourier coordinates and so
$$ e^{t\Delta}f(x) = (F^{-1} \circ M'\circ F)f(x) = (2\pi)^{-n} \int\int e^{i\langle{x-y, \xi\rangle}}e^{-t\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2}f(y)dyd\xi. $$
We can then swap the order of integration to get

$$\int e^{i\langle{x-y, \xi\rangle}}e^{-t\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2}d\xi = \pi^{n/2}t^{-n/2} e^{-\lvert{x-y\rvert}^2/(4t)} $$
which multiplied by $(2\pi)^{-n}$ gives the correct normalisation factor $(4\pi t)^{-n/2}$ out front.

For the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operator $L = -\frac{1}{2}\Delta + x \cdot \nabla$, I am trying to apply the same ideas to get the Mehler kernel which according to http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Research/Preprints/2012/12.pdf (p14) is given by
$$ M_t(x, y) = \frac{1}{\pi^{n/2}(1 - e^{-2t})^{n/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{\lvert{y-e^{-t}x\rvert}^2}{1-e^{-2t}}\right). $$
If I apply the same ideas, $L$ in Fourier coordinates should be multiplication by $\frac{1}{2}\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2 + i\langle{x, \xi\rangle}$ so I should be able to recover the kernel of $e^{-tL}$ through the integral
$$ \int e^{i\langle{x-y, \xi\rangle}}e^{-\frac{t}{2}\lvert{\xi\rvert}^2 - it\langle{x, \xi\rangle}} d\xi $$
but I can't get this to agree even in dimension $1$. What am I doing wrong?